# JavaScript Regex Match Value + Comma and Replace with Empty or space

Tags: regex, replace

I am using javascript .replace function to replace match content/pattern but problem it replace match content but didn't get the comma associate with, Like:

```
i have var a = 'gJDjOw0ern8,-4oCq2Vw4GQ,fjsrhmUhK60';
and b = 'gJDjOw0ern8,-4oCq2Vw4GQ';
```

and i want to remove only match values, like the above example have i need this output after replace:" `a = 'fjsrhmUhK60';`

But what i am getting is: `a =' ,fjsrhmUhK60';`

everytime values replace but the associate comma didn't replace with empty or space.

my code: `a = a.replace(b,'');`

i don't want to remove all commas, reason after every unique value have its comma separator,

5 unique values have 4 commas:

```
654987987dsfdsf,5487987fsdfdsfsd,dsf8ds7987987,dsfdsfd779,sdfdsfdf
```

so only want to remove the matched value and the associated comma with space or empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to the regex approach:

```
// arg1 : the source string
// arg2 : the values to remove from source string
function stringDiff(a,b){
  var b=b.split(',');
  return a.split(',').filter(function(v){
    return b.indexOf(v)==-1;
  }).join(',');
}

var a = 'gJDjOw0ern8,-4oCq2Vw4GQ,fjsrhmUhK60';
var b = 'gJDjOw0ern8,-4oCq2Vw4GQ';

stringDiff(a,b); // return:fjsrhmUhK60
```

Comment: You understand what i want, without any bug its working perfectly, amazing job Crayon.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var r = a.replace(new RegExp(b + ",*"), '');
//=> "fjsrhmUhK60"
```

`new RegExp(b + ",*")` will build a regex using variable `b` followed by 0 or more comma.

**PS:** If `a` and `b` may contain regex meta characters then you will need to escape those chars in `b`. Something like this should work:

```
var r = a.replace(new RegExp(b.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&') + ",*"), '');
```

Comment: Your first example work well it create new bug, which is i have 4 unique id's now: `'saHJ_S-MEiY,SEUXMVt6Fik,6KtOcX8xOY8,jmMn4zzdyqc,ARTDCAGGS5k`

And i matched: `var b = 'saHJ_S-MEiY,ARTDCAGGS5k';`

you code not work when i match the first id and the last id, but between ids i can match and replace with associate comma now, can you check this what's now new issue its.

Comment: Didn't get your comment. Can you clarify what is `a` and what is `b` and what is expected output?

Comment: bad regex. try with `a='foo,bar';b='bar';` or `a='foo,bar';b='foobar,bar'`

Comment: @CrayonViolent: Use: `a.replace(new RegExp(",*" + "\\b" + b + ",*"), '')`

Comment: still bad regex. again, try `a='foo,bar';b='foobar,bar'`

Comment: i'm going to give you a hint: if you want to do this the regex way, you need to use lookarounds

Comment: honestly i think you misunderstood the question. OP has 2 lists and he wants to remove all the items from list1 that are in list2.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava for your help, it help me little, but not much what actually i want, i appreciate you response to my question very first. thankyou so much.

Comment: Yes, looks like it as title and description mentions `value + comma`. It was more of array intersection problem.